# Faster approach cell array matlab

Tags: matlab, cell-array

Referred to the question [Any other approach for Fasters implementation - matlab cell array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36689941/any-other-approach-for-fasters-implementation-matlab-cell-array/36703309?noredirect=1#comment60995580_36703309).

I got result in mycell as

```
size(mycell) = 1*10000*15,
```

with

```
mycell(:,:,1) = 1 *10000*1 % but only contain 9 values
mycell(:,:,2) = 1 *10000*2 % but only contain 50 values
```

So I used:

```
mycell = arrayfun(@(segId)cat(2, mycell{:,:,segId}), 1:size(mycell, 3), 'uni', 0);
```

But this statement is also taking alot of time. Is there anyway to implement it much faster?

I get result like:

```
mycell = 
column 1     2      3   ..............15
     <1*9> <1*50> <1*111> ........ 15 cells
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I take it that by `mycell = 1*10000*15` you mean `size(mycell) = 1 * 10000 * 15`, and not that `mycell` is a scalar with value 150,000?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry. mycell was created of size = 1 * 10000 * 15